# Open Browser does not work after updating to Katalon 6.0.5

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I updated to Katalon 6.0.5 from 5.9.1 and when I wrote my new test case in the manual mode it is failing on the OpenBrowser method, I have attached a screenshot of my error below, which indicates the reason as 'com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url'.

Ironically the test cases which I have created prior to this upgrade get executed without an issue, this leads me to believe that it may be something to do with the object capture in this version but then again I am not sure why its failing on open browser for these new testcases.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuGMR.jpg)

Comment: share with the forum link with you https://forum.katalon.com/t/unable-to-open-browser-with-url-unable-to-open-browser-with-url/8876/4

Comment: Hi Akshay, That solution didn't work out. Even after adding the no sandbox, it continues to fail. I am quite confused every thing worked well prior to this upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

In this new version of Katalon when a new project is created it has three options API/Services, Web and Mobile and the API/Services get selected by default here and I have mistakenly created the project with that option.

I figured this out when I got a fresh project at that point I selected the Web option properly and every thing turned out well. Unfortunately, Katalon does not indicate to the user which type of project the user has selected, this could have been avoided at least if there was some sort of label.I hope if anyone encounters the same issue they will know where to look now.

[image]